# How to write or append at a specific key/value of an object in json via python

Tags: python, json

The question is very self explanatory.
I need to write or append at a specific key/value of an object in json via python.

I'm not sure how to do it because I'm not good with JSON but here is an example of how I tried to do it (I know it is wrong).

```
with open('info.json', 'a') as f:
    json.dumps(data, ['key1'])
```

this is the json file:

```
{"key0":"xxxxx@gmail.com","key1":"12345678"}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the JSON file? What does your desired output look like?

Comment: suppose data="random string" then json would be: {"key0":"xxxxx@gmail.com","key1":"12345678random string"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical usage pattern for [JSONs in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) is to load the JSON object into Python, edit that object, and then write the resulting object back out to file.

```
import json

with open('info.json', 'r') as infile:
    my_data = json.load(infile)
    
my_data['key1'] = my_data['key1'] + 'random string'
# perform other alterations to my_data here, as appropriate ...

with open('scratch.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(my_data, outfile)
```

Contents of 'info.json' are now

```
{"key0": "xxxxx@gmail.com", "key1": "12345678random string"}
```

The key operations were `json.load(fp)`, which deserialized the file into a Python object in memory, and `json.dump(obj, fp)`, which reserialized the edited object to the file being written out.

This may be unsuitable if you're editing very large JSON objects and cannot easily pull the entire object into memory at once, but if you're just trying to learn the basics of Python's JSON library it should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

An example for appending data to a json file using `json` library:

```py
import json

raw =  '{ "color": "green",  "type": "car" }'
data_to_add = { "gear": "manual" }  
parsed = json.loads(raw) 
parsed.update(data_to_add)
```

You can then save your changes with `json.dumps`.